# Showing $x_1 + x_2 + ... + x_n = a$ is compact if $x_i \geq 0$

Tags: real-analysis

I was wondering how we can show something like $x + y + z = 6$ is compact. Specifically, I would like to extend it to any number of variables. Cleary it's bounded as $0 \leq x_i \leq a$, bug I don't know how to show it contains all of it's boundary points in arbitrary dimensions.

Specifically, is there a "slick" way to do this, like showing a continuous mapping from another compact set? I am allowed to use the fact that a unit sphere in arbitrary dimensions is compact, but not sure how to use that here.

Thank you!

Comment: If $f(x,y,z)=x+y+z$, then $f$ is continuous, so $f^{-1}(\{6\})$ is closed in $\mathbb R^3$. You've established that $f^{-1}(\{6\})\cap\{(x,y,z)\mid x,y,z\geq 0\}$ is bounded, so by Heine-Borel it is compact.

Comment: So simply saying that $x+y+z$ is continuous, and compact sets map to compact sets, and since $6$ is compact, so is $x+y+z = 6$? That doesn't seem rigorous...

Comment: I'm not using the fact that continuous functions map compact sets to compact sets, but that the preimage of a *closed* set under a continuous map is *closed*.

Comment: Take the example $f(x) = 0$ where $x \in (0,1)$. Clearly, $0$ is closed, but $(0,1)$ is not closed. I don't think what you said is true.

Comment: What is the domain of $f$? $(0,1)$ is closed in $(0,1)$. What I am saying are essentially definitions of continuity and compactness (compactness in $\mathbb R^n$).

Comment: It's not closed in R.

Comment: But that doesn't matter, as the domain of your function is $(0,1)$. It doesn't know that $\mathbb R$ exists. In general, closed sets of $(0,1)$ in the subspace topology are of the form $(0,1)\cap A$, where $A$ is a closed set in $\mathbb R$. Clearly $A=[0,1]$ is closed.

Comment: So you mean if we have a function with a domain and range, and we look at the image and it's compact on R, it's pre-image will be compact on the domain?

Comment: No, I don't mean that, nothing I wrote implies that. For example $f^{-1}(\{6\})$ is not compact, even though $\{6\}$ is compact, because it is unbounded. But it is closed by the closed set definition of continuity. The set $\{(x,y,z)\mid x,y,z\geq 0 \}$ is closed in $\mathbb R^3$ so $f^{-1}(\{6\})\cap\{(x,y,z)\mid x,y,z\geq 0\}$ is closed as the intersection of two closed sets. But it is also bounded. So it is closed and bounded, therefore it is compact by Heine-Borel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we have a sphere $x_1^2 + x_2^2+ \ldots + x_n^2 = a$ (which we can prove to be closed easily by constructing open balls around all points in the complement), then take the continuous map $f(x_1, \ldots, x_n) = (x_1^2, \ldots, x_n^2)$, which maps the entire sphere to the plane $y_1+\ldots+y_n=a$. This is because if we have a point $(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ on the sphere, then the function takes this point to $(x_1^2, \ldots, x_n^2)$, but $x_1^2 + \ldots + x_n^2 = a$ which means that $(x_1^2, \ldots, x_n^2)$ is on the plane.

As shown, we just took any point on the sphere and mapped it (using a continuous function) to plane in question. Furthermore, every point in the desired portion of the plane is reached because if we have $(y_1, \ldots, y_n)$ in the desired portion of the plane, then we know that all the $y_i\geq 0$, and so taking square roots makes sense, and we know the point $(\sqrt{y_1}, \ldots, \sqrt{y_n})$ is on the sphere.

Thus the map is continuous and surjective (though not injective), and because continuous functions take compact sets to compact sets, the desired portion of the plane is compact.